# Plot Multicolored line based on conditional in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a pandas dataframe with three columns and a datetime index

```
date        px_last  200dma     50dma           
2014-12-24  2081.88 1953.16760  2019.2726
2014-12-26  2088.77 1954.37975  2023.7982
2014-12-29  2090.57 1955.62695  2028.3544
2014-12-30  2080.35 1956.73455  2032.2262
2014-12-31  2058.90 1957.66780  2035.3240
```

I would like to make a time series plot of the 'px_last' column that is colored green if on the given day the 50dma is above the 200dma value and colored red if the 50dma value is below the 200dma value. I have seen this example, but can't seem to make it work for my case
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html

Comment: Anyone have a way to extend this to 3 or more colors?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example to do it without `matplotlib.collections.LineCollection`. The idea is to first identify the cross-over point and then using a `plot` function via groupby.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# simulate data
# =============================
np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame({'px_last': 100 + np.random.randn(1000).cumsum()}, index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=1000, freq='B'))
df['50dma'] = pd.rolling_mean(df['px_last'], window=50)
df['200dma'] = pd.rolling_mean(df['px_last'], window=200)
df['label'] = np.where(df['50dma'] > df['200dma'], 1, -1)


# plot
# =============================
df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='any')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def plot_func(group):
    global ax
    color = 'r' if (group['label'] < 0).all() else 'g'
    lw = 2.0
    ax.plot(group.index, group.px_last, c=color, linewidth=lw)

df.groupby((df['label'].shift() * df['label'] < 0).cumsum()).apply(plot_func)

# add ma lines
ax.plot(df.index, df['50dma'], 'k--', label='MA-50')
ax.plot(df.index, df['200dma'], 'b--', label='MA-200')
ax.legend(loc='best')
```

[image]

Comment: I was getting a StopIteration Error because, plot_func wasn't returning anything so I just added the line to the function
    
    return group
besides that, that is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @Mishiko it's quite strange. the code runs properly on my PC. Can you upload your sample data (via dropbox sharelink or google driver) if that's not proprietary?

Comment: I was getting the same error with your random data, but yes I will upload a link to some sample data of mine later today.

Comment: @Mishiko Make sure you have the most recent version of `pandas` and `matplotlib`. :-)

Comment: Is there anyway to extend this to 3 or more colors?

Comment: Any way of doing this as of 2023?

Answer (score 10):

Building on [@Jianxun Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014134/jianxun-li)'s answer, here's a version that's more easily extendible to 3+ colors:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Simulate data
np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'px_last': 100 + np.random.randn(1000).cumsum()},
    index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=1000, freq='B'),
)
df['50dma'] = df['px_last'].rolling(window=50, center=False).mean()
df['200dma'] = df['px_last'].rolling(window=200, center=False).mean()

## Apply labels
df['label'] = 'out of bounds'
df.loc[abs(df['50dma'] - df['200dma']) >= 7, 'label'] = '|50dma - 200dma| >= 7'
df.loc[abs(df['50dma'] - df['200dma']) < 7, 'label'] = '|50dma - 200dma| < 7'
df.loc[abs(df['50dma'] - df['200dma']) < 5, 'label'] = '|50dma - 200dma| < 5'
df.loc[abs(df['50dma'] - df['200dma']) < 3, 'label'] = '|50dma - 200dma| < 3'
df = df[df['label'] != 'out of bounds']

## Convert labels to colors
label2color = {
    '|50dma - 200dma| < 3': 'green',
    '|50dma - 200dma| < 5': 'yellow',
    '|50dma - 200dma| < 7': 'orange',
    '|50dma - 200dma| >= 7': 'red',
}
df['color'] = df['label'].apply(lambda label: label2color[label])

# Create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def gen_repeating(s):
    """Generator: groups repeated elements in an iterable
    E.g.
        'abbccc' -> [('a', 0, 0), ('b', 1, 2), ('c', 3, 5)]
    """
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        j = i
        while j < len(s) and s[j] == s[i]:
            j += 1
        yield (s[i], i, j-1)
        i = j

## Add px_last lines
for color, start, end in gen_repeating(df['color']):
    if start > 0: # make sure lines connect
        start -= 1
    idx = df.index[start:end+1]
    df.loc[idx, 'px_last'].plot(ax=ax, color=color, label='')

## Add 50dma and 200dma lines
df['50dma'].plot(ax=ax, color='k', ls='--', label='MA$_{50}$')
df['200dma'].plot(ax=ax, color='b', ls='--', label='MA$_{200}$')

## Get artists and labels for legend and chose which ones to display
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

## Create custom artists
g_line = plt.Line2D((0,1),(0,0), color='green')
y_line = plt.Line2D((0,1),(0,0), color='yellow')
o_line = plt.Line2D((0,1),(0,0), color='orange')
r_line = plt.Line2D((0,1),(0,0), color='red')

## Create legend from custom artist/label lists
ax.legend(
    handles + [g_line, y_line, o_line, r_line],
    labels + [
        '|MA$_{50} - $MA$_{200}| < 3$',
        '|MA$_{50} - $MA$_{200}| < 5$',
        '|MA$_{50} - $MA$_{200}| < 7$',
        '|MA$_{50} - $MA$_{200}| \geq 7$',
    ],
    loc='best',
)

# Display plot
plt.show()
```

I've also added a fancy-ish legend.

[image: multicolor-line]