# How to plot line on different columns according to categorical variable

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe containing a time series with two columns as follows:

```
            dailyp  kind
date        
2015-01-01  165.0   national
2015-01-02  210.0   not_festive
2015-01-03  222.0   not_festive
2015-01-04  190.0   not_festive
2015-01-05  200.0   not_festive
...     ...     ...
2019-12-28  260.0   not_festive
2019-12-29  226.0   not_festive
2019-12-30  216.0   not_festive
2019-12-31  189.0   not_festive
2020-01-01  237.0   not_festive
```

I have written a function to plot the time series differing on the value of `kind` that goes as follows:

```
def plot_timeseries_by_category(df, category_col):
  # Get the unique years from the index
    years = df.index.year.unique()
    
    # Create a subplot for each year
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(years), 1, figsize=(10, len(years) * 5))
    if len(years) == 1:
        axes = [axes]
        
    for year, ax in zip(years, axes):
        # Filter the data for the current year
        df_year = df[df.index.year == year]
        
        # Create all neccesary colors
        colors = {category: f'C{index}' for index, category in enumerate(df[category_col].unique())}
        print(df_year.index)
        # Groupby category and plot
        for category, group in df_year.groupby(category_col):
            
            group.plot('index', 'dailyp', marker='o', ax=ax, color=colors[category], label=category)
        
        ax.set_title(str(year))
        ax.legend()
```

The code also breaks the time series by years, but that works just fine. But instead of plotting a single line with different colors depending on the category, it plots a line for each category. I want to achieve what is shown in the approved answer of this post [Plot Multicolored line based on conditional in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590184/plot-multicolored-line-based-on-conditional-in-python), but couldn't make it work.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What exactly do you want?  You might find it helpful to use a pivot and second plot. Maybe a new feature will help.

Comment: It is shown just on the answer, the link posted there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'date': ['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-04', '2015-01-05', 
             '2019-12-28', '2019-12-29', '2019-12-30', '2019-12-31', '2020-01-01'], 
    'dailyp': [165.0, 210.0, 222.0, 190.0, 200.0, 
                260.0, 226.0, 216.0, 189.0, 237.0], 
    'kind': ['national', 'not_festive', 'not_festive', 'not_festive', 'not_festive', 
             'not_festive', 'not_festive', 'not_festive', 'not_festive', 'not_festive']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('date')


def plot_timeseries_by_category(df, category_col):
    # Get the unique years from the index
    years = df.index.year.unique()

    # Create a subplot for each year
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(years), 1, figsize=(10, len(years) * 5))
    if len(years) == 1:
        axes = [axes]

    for year, ax in zip(years, axes):
        # Filter the data for the current year
        df_year = df[df.index.year == year].reset_index().reset_index()

        # Create all neccesary colors
        colors = {category: f'C{index}' for index, category in enumerate(df[category_col].unique())}

        # Groupby category and plot
        for category, group in df_year.groupby(category_col):
            group = group.set_index('index')
            ax.plot(group.index, group['dailyp'], marker='o', color=colors[category], label=category)

        ax.set_title(str(year))
        ax.legend()

plot_timeseries_by_category(df, 'kind')
plt.show()
```

which will return a plot for each year
[image]